# How can I find elements from a Perl array that match elements in a second array?

Tags: perl

I have two arrays

```
@one = ("1|1|the|dog|ran", "1|2|a|x|b", "2|8|e|s|e");
@two = ("1|2|a|x|b", "1|1|down|the|street", "2|8|e|s|e");
```

I need to match them by the first two "|" separated elements. So that when on $one[0] the search would return $two[1].

There are millions of lines in each array so I need the fastest way to do this.

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusion. I want to treat the first 2 "|" separated elements (ie. 1|2, 2|1) as a key for the array, loop through the first array and search the second array using that key to get the values in the second array. Does that help?

Comment: When you say "by the first to", did you actually mean "by the first TWO"? Because that'd make a lot more sense.

Comment: Start looking here in the Perl FAQ: [How do I find the intersection of two arrays?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays-)

Comment: Given there are millions of elements in each array, are we concerned that you cannot hold an entire array in memory all at once?  Are the arrays going to grow over time so that memory does become an issue?

Comment: If you have "millions" of lines in your arrays - which seems to be odd in the first place - perhaps you should consider moving your data to a database instead.

Comment: @DavidO Ya that might be a problem. When you take about memory is there a "perl memory amount" or are you taking about the computer's memory?

Comment: Perl doesn't place any arbitrary constraints on your memory usage.  You've got what's available in physical, and then you go into swap (slow).  I ask, because if that becomes an issue, the algorithm changes.

Comment: Guys, this whole memory thing is a red herring. He already has all his data in memory. He should just use a hash instead of an array for one of them. That doesn't take that much extra memory! The key is never putting the data in `@two`, put it straight into `%two` when you read it in.

Comment: @ikegami Maybe.  I agree it sounds like he's holding both arrays in memory already, so the hash wouldn't be much difference.  I was wondering if near-future growth would be significant enough to design around the issue right now.  If growth rate is slow and memory is big, it's a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- For each record in the second array,
  - Parse the record
  - Add it to a hash keyed by the first two fields.

- For each record in the first array,
  - Parse the record
  - Look in the hash for a record with the appropriate key.
  - If there is one,
    - Do something with it.
```

Comment: If there are millions of lines in each array, it might not be viable to build a hash to compare.

Comment: Hash is the best option, assuming the memory can take it.

Comment: @TLP, I don't see why using a array + hash would use up more memory than array + array with the same data. In fact, you could make do with just a hash since the ones don't need to be kept in memory.

Comment: @ikegami I haven't worked with hashs all that much. How do I add the second array keyed by the first two fields?

Comment: The record is added, not the array. `1|2` would do fine for key, and would use less memory than a Hash of Hash

Comment: @ikegami I know what you mean. It all depends on whether the data is actually read into the arrays, or put there directly in code. Either way, it feels as though if speed is an issue, a database might be better.

Comment: @TLP, Database will make things way slower.